# Swift: command center not working, even though I explicitly set buttons to enable?

Tags: audio, swift3, avaudiosession, mpremotecommandcenter

Ok, having some problems with Apple's command center here, playing background audio/on lock screen and cant understand why. Seems pretty simple but I don't even have the episode information displaying reliably in command center, definitely cant play/pause.

First I start the Audio session:

```
  do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
                print("Playback OK")
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("Session is Active")
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
```

then I set up my command center buttons to be enabled explicitly:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()


        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true

        commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = true
//        commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
//        commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = true

        commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(togglePlayPause))
//        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(nextTrackForward))
//        commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(nextTrackBack))

        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ffPressed))
        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(rwPressed))
```

Here is the lldb plist keys if that matters for audio:

[image]

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your question is old but someone could need this too, so this is how I did it :

***Swift 5***

```
let player = AVPlayer()

func commandCenter () {
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget         { (commandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in  self.play();   return .success }
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget        { (commandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in  self.pause();  return .success }
}

func pause () {
    player.pause ()
    print("paused")
}

func play () {
    player.play()
    print("play")
}
```

You don't need to enable commandCenter.playCommand to *true*